# How to write this Java Class in C# Class format

Tags: java, c#, static

How to write this Java Class in C# Class format

```
 public final class JsonParserResolver {
        // PlacesApiJsonParser is an Interface
        public static final PlacesApiJsonParser JSON_PARSER;

        static {
                boolean hasGson;
          try {
              Class.forName("com.google.gson.Gson");
              hasGson = true;
          } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
              hasGson = false;
          }

          JSON_PARSER = hasGson ? new GsonPlacesApiJsonParser() : new 
          AndroidPlacesApiJsonParser();
        }

        private JsonParserResolver() {
            throw new RuntimeException("No instances");
        }
    }
```

The class static member is resolving stuff automatically on Class instantiation. This is a very useful

Hold your horses this is where I am, I get a little stuck on the `JSON_PARSER`

```
namespace WorkSampleBookSearch
{
    public final class JsonParserResolver
    {
        public static final PlacesApiJsonParser JSON_PARSER;

        static {
         boolean hasGson;


        JSON_PARSER = hasGson? new GsonPlacesApiJsonParser() : new AndroidPlacesApiJsonParser();
        }

    private JsonParserResolver()
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("No instances");
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Whas is your concrete doubt?

Comment: This seems much too broad a question.  What have you tried? What aspect(s) of the Java are you having trouble rewriting?

Comment: You can't write something like `static {}` inside the `c#` class, I assume it is an anonymous class inside a class.

Comment: I know, this is why I ask the question to learn, the `static {}` Java code must have some equivalence in C# right?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44259648/anonymous-classes-in-c-sharp

Comment: Probably you need something like `static hasGson = Type.GetType("TypeName,DllName") != null;`.

Comment: static {...} in Java just corresponds to a static constructor in C#.